# To join four table in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

**MaingroupTable**

```
MubGroupCodeid       MainName      maincode
1                     Health          098
2                     Social          078
```

**SubGroup Table**

```
SubGroupCodeid     SubName         subcode

1                  Nursing          211
2                  Civics           224
```

**SubandMainGroup**  table

```
subandmainid      **MubGroupCodeid**       **subgroupcodeid**       
1                    1                      1         
2                    2                       2
```

**Student Table**

```
studid   studname      **subandmainid** (foriegn key of **subandmain group**  table)
1       Alex            1  
2       siraj           2
```

then I want to join and concatinate studname-maingroupcode-subgroupcode   to  get output   like below

```
  Alex-098-211 
  siraj-078-224
```

Comment: Hello, could you please be more specific on your question  and post what did you try so far ?

Comment: What have you tried? Is this a homework question? This is a fairly basic JOIN. http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: I want to concatenate all studname    with their maingroupcode and subgroupcode

Comment: It's fairly obvious, that the similarly-spelled column names are meant to be joined together.  You should at least attempt the join proposed in the question and make clear what part of the problem you can't accomplish (such as string concatenation of the fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use join and concat all the required column by using ||

```
select s.studname ||'-'||subG.subcode ||'-' M.maincode
                from 
               Student s join SubandMainGroup  subM on s.subandmainid=subM.subandmainid      
                 join SubGroup subG on subG.SubGroupCodeid=subM.subgroupcodeid
                 join MaingroupTable M on M.MubGroupCodeid=subM.MubGroupCodeid
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started and explain the joins. You'll probably also want to do some casting for the maincode and subcode, but since it's not 100% clear they aren't already varchar values I left that out.

```
SELECT s.studname + '-' + m.maincode + '-' + s.subcode
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN SubandMainGroup smg on smg.subandmainid = s.subandmainid
INNER JOIN MainGroup m on m.mubgroupcodeid = smg.mubgroupcodeid
INNER JOIN SubGroup s on s.subgroupcodeid = smg.subgroupcodeid
```

Comment: Should throw isnull() or coalesce() around them also.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to solve the problem.

```
select stu.studname + '-'+mgrp.maincode +'-'+sgrp.subcode from Student_ stu 
join Maingroup mgrp on stu.studid=mgrp.MubGroupCodeid 
join SubGroup sgrp on sgrp.SubGroupCodeid=stu.studid
```